# Tcl/tk - how to make yesno messageBox in thread visible

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have created a simple thread to continuously display a message box till the user deos not want to some operation. Following is the code:

```
thread::create { while [tk_messageBox -message "Do you want to Exit?!!" -type yesno] {
    doSomething
}}
```

But there is no message box displayed although the thread is created.
How can I really see these messageboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make Tk be present in the thread as well; only the Thread package is present by default in subordinate threads:

```
thread::create {
    package require Tk
    while [tk_messageBox -message "Do you want to Exit?!!" -type yesno] {
        doSomething
    }
}
```

Also, you need to fix a bunch of other problems in your code.

1. ***Always*** put the condition of a `while` in `{`braces`}`. Without that, the dynamic parts of the expression will only be evaluated once, which really isn't what you ever want with a `while`.
2. Make sure your thread does `thread::wait`, as that enables improved process and thread management. Your message box loop needs to be rewritten entirely.

This might lead to this code:

```
thread::create {
    package require Tk

    proc periodicallyMaybeDoSomething {} {
        if {[tk_messageBox -message "Do you want to Exit?!!" -type yesno]} {
            thread::exit
        }
        doSomething
        # pick a better delay maybe?
        after 1 periodicallyMaybeDoSomething
    }
    after 1 periodicallyMaybeDoSomething

    thread::wait
}
```

If you're using 8.6, you may be able to use coroutines to make the code more elegant.

Comment: Thanks Donal - Tried it worked fine and opened the dialog but on clicking no showed error dialog box with contents "can not find channel named "stdout"
can not find channel named "stdout"
    while executing
"puts doSomething"
    (procedure "periodicallyMaybeDoSomething" line 5)
    invoked from within
"periodicallyMaybeDoSomething"
    ("after" script)"
Any ideas how to refer to stdout in thread body